# chai-as-promised not failing typescript tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm trying to use [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised) in my [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) test for some typescript code. I can't quite get the syntax right. So I setup a minimal reproducer:

### index.ts

```
// Sample promise that resolves on red, fails on other values
export const getRedColor = async (color: string): Promise<string> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (color === 'red') {
        resolve(color);
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`You picked ${color}, should be red`));
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
```

### index.spec.ts

First I used async/await to write a test as control, the first 2 pass, the second two are designed to fail.

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import 'mocha';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
import { getRedColor, isRedColor } from '../src/index';
import { describe } from 'mocha';

describe('Testing failing promises with async/await', () => {
  it('should pass on red', async () => {
    let result = await getRedColor('red');
    expect(result).to.equal('red');
  });

  it('should throw on blue', async () => {
    try {
      let result = await getRedColor('blue');
      expect.fail('SHould not succeed');
    } catch (e: any) {
      expect(e.message).to.equal('You picked blue, should be red');
    }
  });

  // Deliberately failing
  it('should fail on blue', async () => {
    let result = await getRedColor('blue');
    expect(result).to.equal('blue');
  });

  // Deliberately failing
  it('should throw on red', async () => {
    try {
      let result = await getRedColor('red');
      expect.fail('Should not succeed');
    } catch (e: any) {
      expect(e.message).to.equal('You picked red, should be red');
    }
  });
});
```

then (in the same file) the same (2 pass/2fail) in chai syntax

### index.spec.ts (continued)

```
describe('Testing failing promises chai-as-promised', () => {
  it('should pass on red', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('red');
    expect(result).to.eventually.equal('red');
  });

  it('should throw on blue', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('blue');
    expect(result).to.eventually.rejectedWith('You picked blue, should be red');
  });

  // Deliberately failing
  it('should fail expecting rejection on red', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('red');
    expect(result).to.eventually.rejected;
  });

  // Deliberately failing
  it('should fail resulting in blue', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('blue');
    expect(result).to.eventually.eql('blue');
  });
});
```

All test pass - so I must do something wrong. I also checked [the documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) which suggests to alter the test to

```
  // Deliberately failing
  it('should fail resulting in blue', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('blue');
    return result.to.eventually.eql('blue');
  });
```

but that leads to an Error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eventually')

What do I miss?

Comment: Don't you need to return the promise from getRedColor first, before chaining the eventually and rejectedWith methods?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? `result` is a returned promise. How would the syntax look like? I suspect that chai-as-promised is patching the promise object, but might need additional setup steps in a typescript environment

Comment: Yes, chai-as-promised extends Chai's assertion library with additional methods that can be chained onto promises. These methods return a new promise. The syntax would be something like [this](https://pastebin.com/5uRjxVwd).

Comment: @JishanShaikh came to the same conclusion yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close. Missing was either a return statement or a call to notify. These is the working code in `return` and `notify()` flavor:

```
describe('Testing failing promises chai-as-promised', () => {
  it('should pass on red', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('red');
    return expect(result).to.eventually.equal('red');
  });

  it('should throw on blue', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('blue');
    return expect(result).to.eventually.rejectedWith('You picked blue, should be red');
  });

describe('Testing failing promises chai-as-promised', () => {
  it('should pass on red', (done) => {
    let result = getRedColor('red');
    expect(result).to.eventually.equal('red').notify(done);
  });

  it('should throw on blue', (done) => {
    let result = getRedColor('blue');
    expect(result).to.eventually.rejectedWith('You picked blue, should be red').notify(done);
  });
});
```

Hope that helps someone struggling with the same details

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you were close. I recently ran into the "every async/Promise test passes when it should fail" problem. There's a few parts that come together to solve it.

Although the `done` completion function works, it limits you to one async call per test. I find it a bit cumbersome to read as well.

The approach I landed on is an `async` method and `await` on the `expect` call. That last part wasn't obvious to me so I thought I'd explain it to anyone else encountering this...

Here's one of your original cases that should fail but wasn't:

```js
  // original
  it('should fail expecting rejection on red', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('red');
    expect(result).to.be.eventually.rejected;
  });
```

Here's your posted answer, which works but uses the `done` completion function:

```js
  // first cut
  it('should pass on red', (done) => {
    let result = getRedColor('red');
    expect(result).to.eventually.equal('red').notify(done);
  });
```

My suggested answer is use `async` and `await`:

```js
  // Use async and await
  it('should pass on red', async () => {
    await expect(getRedColor('red')).eventually.equals('red')
  })
```

Likewise, testing for a failed promise:

```js
  // Original
  it('should fail expecting rejection on red', () => {
    let result = getRedColor('red');
    expect(result).to.be.eventually.rejected;
  });
```

First cut using `done` (I don't personally like but does work):

```js
  // first cut from earlier answer
  it('should throw on blue', (done) => {
    let result = getRedColor('blue');
    expect(result).to.be.eventually.rejectedWith('You picked blue, should be red').notify(done);
  });
```

Final:

```js
  // use async and await
  it('should throw on blue', async () => {
    await expect(getRedColor('blue')).eventually.rejectedWith('You picked blue, should be red')
  })
```

This lets you put as many promise tests as you want together:

```js
  it('test red works', async () => {
    await expect(getRedColor('red')).eventually.equals('red')
    await expect(getRedColor('blue')).eventually.rejectedWith('You picked blue, should be red')
  })
```